# How can I take the intersection of two sets then remove those elements from original set using one line of code for the 'for loop'?

Tags: python, set

I am trying to take the intersection of two sets, then remove these elements from the
two original sets. Here is my code:

```
A = {1,2,3,4}
B = {2,3,7,8}

AB_intersec = A.intersection(B)

A.remove(I for I in AB_intersec)
```

I am getting a `KeyError: <generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f8baaa07ac0>` error.
I kind of understand why this is- because `I for I in AB_intersec` is a generator- am I right? If so how can I amend the code (while keeping it to one line) to make it work? I have tried doing your normal for loop across multiple lines and that works, but I would like to do it using one line if possible. Thanks

Comment: please add the tag for the programming language that you are using

Comment: There's no need for loops when working with sets. `A.difference(AB_intersec)`, or shorthand `A - AB_intersec` will remove the new set from A. PS, might want to tag it `Python`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in one line:

```
A, B = A-B, B-A
```